# Photoshop pixelart - Pen tool draws outside of grid

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pixel-art

I used to create pixel art in Aspire and now am trying to use Photoshop.
When I use the 1px pen tool, the 1px brush and 1px grid do not align properly. What is going on?

[image: pixelart grid]

Comment: I can't replicate the issue. When I use a 1 px pencil with 1 px grid, it works just fine. See the [screen capture here](https://imgur.com/a/lEbsS12).

Comment: Is it possible that your grid origin has been moved?

Comment: There are applications designed specifically for pixel art. Photoshop is not one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your *grid* settings.

Press `ctrl+k` (or `cmd+k` on mac) to open the *Preferences* window and enter *Guides, Grid & Slices*.

Under *Grid* make sure to set the unit to *Pixels* and make sure that *Gridline Every* equals *Subdivisions*. For example you could set both to 10:

[image: Guide, Grid and Slices]

Alternatively, if you have GPU rendering enabled, there is a built-in 1px grid available. Toggle it with *View > Show > Pixel Grid*.

Comment: I did check my grid settings, they were set as you recommended. After I toggle Pixel Grid my issue fixed.