# Photoshop's normal grid is smaller than the set pixel size

Tags: adobe-photoshop, grids, pixel

I set up a 10x10 pixels image in PS V21.0.2.

[image]

I turned on the pixel grid in `View>Show>Pixel Grid` and turned off the Grid in `View>Show>Grid`, and zoomed in to my image.

I however, saw no pixel grid. Protip if you're having the same problem: I eventually figured out I COULD see the pixel grid, but they were set to a white color, not visible on my background.

But whilst trying to fix the above, I tried setting the grid in `Preferences>Guides, Grid & Slices>Grid`. I changed the `Gridline every` to `1 pixels` with `1 subdivision`.

[image]

Then I turned on the grid, and what I saw was this:

[image]

What you are seeing above is my 10x10 image where I placed a black 1x1 pixel on the diagonal. As you can see, the grid shows 12.5x12.5 squares... My brush size (set to 1 px) shows up bigger than each individual square in the grid.

Here is the same image with `pixel grid` turned ON, and `grid` turned off, and a different background color so you can see the pixel grid:
[image]

As you can see, the grid shows 10x10 squares... as it should be.

Why do the grid settings lie?

Comment: This question has a duplicate. I'll see if I can find it later.

Comment: I found [this related question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/109708/84899), but I'm not sure it helps you. If your settings really are what you show here it seems like buggy behavior. Could it be related to GPU rendering? Is the grid also wrong if you disable GPU rendering? Does the grid also do this when pixel grid is turned off? What happens if you make for example 10 px grid with 10 subdivisions?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate this but it works fine.

[image]

My guess is that you somehow resized the document and now it's not 10x10.

Comment: Even if the document was resized the grid should still be 1x1 px. Could it be some bug related to GPU rendering and the pixel grid?

Comment: This is not an answer. In fact, as explained in the original post -- the diagonal line you see are black pixels made with a 1x1 pencil. As you can see, the image is 10x10 as I could draw 10 of those. So the image was not resized. The grid just does not line up correctly.

Comment: @KamielDev This is an answer to a question that is not a question really. First of all what you are doing? 10 by 10 with a grid line on every pixel? WTF is that?
However I did try to replicate it as a potential bug in PS but it didn't happen. Case closed. You might have the wrong/old driver or something.
Keep in mind that your question is not just for you, other people will find it and they will see my answer and my answer is useful, because they will understand that this doesn't happen for everyone.

Comment: @Komental you replicated my steps and showed the feature works on your end. Then you suggested I messed up and resized my document. As you can see in the OP (image of Canvas size), that was clearly not the case. 

(Besides, what is not to understand when I'm telling you I'm showing you a 10x10 image with black 1x1 pixels going down diagonally from top left to bottom right?? That was actually explicitly there to show you that the document was 10x10 pixels, and not 'accidentally resized')
Wolff was the one who made a valid suggestion. Not you.

Comment: @KamielDev You ask "Why do the grid settings lie?"  ... well I tried your nonsense and grid settings didn't lie. As far as I understand you would be happier if I didn't try and didn't post but guess what ... I already did.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the solution to this issue, which I also had.

If you go into the Units and Rulers tab of Preferences you'll find options for Rulers and Type under the Units heading. Mine was set to Pixels and Points, respectively. If you change the Type to Pixels it should fix your problem.

Comment: If this really works it must be some kind of bug. The unit for type shouldn't have an effect on grids. Can you reintroduce the problem by switching back to points?